# Renaming Key of Item in Collection with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I have a collection as follows:

```
Set NodeColl = New Collection
NodeColl.Add "Node 1", "Node 1"
NodeColl.Add "Node 2", "Node 2"
NodeColl.Add "Node 3", "Node 3"
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to rename the keys of selective items without affecting other items or the collection itself. For example, something like NodeColl.Items("Node 1").Key = "Some string"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, you will need to add & remove manually;

```
with NodeColl
    .add .Item("Node 2"), "New Key", , "Node 2"
    .remove "Node 2"
end with
```

Or use a `Dictionary` which allows this, either by adding a reference to *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* or;

```
dim NodeColl as object: Set NodeColl = createobject("Scripting.dictionary")
NodeColl.add "key for Node 1", "Node 1"
NodeColl.add "key for Node 2", "Node 2"
NodeColl.add "key for Node 3", "Node 3"

'//direct rename allowed;
NodeColl.Key("key for Node 2") = "New Key here"
```